# Alter Table doesn't work under MS Access 64 bit. Why?

Tags: ms-access, 64-bit, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to write a simple function to resize a text field in MS Access 64 bit version under Windows 7.  It fails with the error 3420, object invalid or no longer set.  Why is this?  Can't you alter a table in code anymore under MS Access 64bit version?

Here is the code:

```
Private Function ResizeSingleTextField(sTableName As String, _
                                       sFieldName As String, _
                                       iLength As Integer)

    ResizeSingleTextField = False

    Dim sSQL As String

    sSQL = "ALTER TABLE " & sTableName & " " _
    & "ALTER COLUMN " & sFieldName & " " _
    & "TEXT (" & iLength & ")"

    CurrentDb.Execute (sSQL)

    ResizeSingleTextField = True
    Exit Function

End Function


Public Sub TestIt()

    Dim result As Boolean

    result = ResizeSingleTextField("GregTest", "MyTextField", 12)

    Debug.Print result

End Sub
```

Comment: What line does it throw the error on?

Comment: It fails on the line CurrentDb.Execute(sSQL).  See the other comment below.

Comment: It looks like this is an actual bug (since there's a hotfix for it), but your code bothers me. I'd not use CurrentDB, but instead assign the database object to a variable, and execute from that (which guarantees persistence, whereas using CurrentDB means the database object returned exists on that single line; shouldn't relevant here, but I'd still do it). Also, you should never all CurrentDB.Execute without the `dbFailOnError` switch and an error handler.

Comment: Dave, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug in that version of Access. See MS Knowledge Base [Article 2516493](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2516493).

Excerpted here:

> **Issue that this hotfix package fixes**
>   Assume that you try to change the
>   structure of a table by using a Data Definition Language (DDL) query
>   and the ALTER TABLE statement in the 64-bit version of Microsoft
>   Access 2010. The ALTER TABLE statement includes an ALTER COLUMN
>   parameter. In this situation, you receive the following error message:
>   **Object invalid or no longer set**. When you try to execute the DDL query
>   through VBA code, you receive the following error message: Run-time
>   error '3420': Object invalid or no longer set.

There is a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2516493&kbln=en-us) that came out in April to remedy the issue. [Access 2010 Runtime Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26602) came out in August 2011, and according to the release notes includes a fix for this issue.

> Access - "Object invalid or no longer set" error occurs when you try to
>   use an ALTER TABLE query to change a field type or size.